# Skip a validation technical profile conditionally

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to skip a validation technical profile based on a condition?

In my case I have the username and password in a screen. I would like to validate the password only if the user meets a certain criteria. If not I would like to redirect the user to reset password page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use preconditions in the User Journey to skip a step a particular Orchestration Step.

Here is an example of a user journey where if the claim of "requiresPasswordReset" is equal to true then the user is taken to the "LocalAccount-PasswordReset" technical profile. Otherwise if false, the user skips over this step to continue the user journey.

Example:

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
      <Value>requiresPasswordReset</Value>
      <Value>True</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordReset" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccount-PasswordReset" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

You can find further documentation on preconditions and user journeys [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Documentation/Features%20part%206.md#specifying-the-user-journeys)